# Error when running green wave example script for rllib flow

Tags: flow-project

I am trying to run the python green_wave rllib example to learn how to implement RL traffic lights and I can not manage to get any of the scripts to run. It gives me an error each time to say "Trials did not complete" and I don't know why.

Here is the error message I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "green_wave.py", line 295, in <module>
    'training_iteration': 200,
  File "/home/charlotte/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/tune/tune.py", line 124, in run_experiments
    raise TuneError("Trials did not complete", errored_trials)
ray.tune.error.TuneError: ('Trials did not complete', [PPO_PO_TrafficLightGridEnv-v0_0])
I0906 13:44:32.994724  9979 store.cc:599] Disconnecting client on fd 10
*** Aborted at 1567773873 (unix time) try "date -d @1567773873" if you are using GNU date ***
PC: @                0x0 (unknown)
*** SIGTERM (@0x3e8000026db) received by PID 9977 (TID 0x7f069fe69740) from PID 9947; stack trace: ***
    @     0x7f069fa6b890 (unknown)
    @     0x7f069ec42b77 epoll_wait
    @           0x454698 boost::asio::detail::epoll_reactor::run()
    @           0x455169 boost::asio::detail::scheduler::run()
    @           0x4512d8 main
    @     0x7f069eb42b97 __libc_start_main
    @           0x4528f1 (unknown)
```

Answer (score 0):

it's unlikely that this error at the bottom is actually the cause of the error that caused the script to fail. Would you mind posting this issue on our Github with the full error log? Sorry for your difficulties!

Comment: Hi Eugene, thanks for your help. I have uploaded my flow files and as much of the output from the terminal as I can here: https://github.com/maunhb/flow/

Comment: Hi Lottie can you open a github issue with this data? It's hard for us to track otherwise.